# dynamic string search in shell script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I have a string in shell script which is

```
list="apr/2018-06-24 17_10_39/2018-06-24 17_10_39.html 

 apr/2018-06-24 17_10_39/access_log.zip

 apr/2018-06-25 17_12_48/2018-06-25 17_12_48.html

 apr/2018-06-25 17_12_48/access_log.zip

 apr/2018-06-26 17_13_36/2018-06-26 17_13_36.html

  DS_BLS_731.dat

 DS_BLS_732.dat

 DS_BLS_733.dat

 apr/2018-06-26 17_13_37/ DS_BLS_739.dat

 apr/2018-06-26 17_13_38/ DS_BLS_738.dat

 apr/2018-06-26 17_13_39/ DS_BLS_737.dat"
```

I need to find DS_BLS_max(sequence number).dat

here DS_BLS_max(sequence number).dat=DS_BLS_739.dat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -o 'DS_BLS_[0-9]*\.dat' <<< "$list" | sort -V | tail -n 1
```

Output:

```
DS_BLS_739.dat
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: however note that `11 < 2 < 3` in lexical sorting.  So if you have `DS_BLS_1739.dat` you won't get it as the max.

Comment: @Cyrus..thanks for reply.The solution is working fine..What if i need to get the whole string.
e.g  apr/2018-06-26 17_13_37/ DS_BLS_739.dat should return  apr/2018-06-26 17_13_37/ DS_BLS_739.dat but its returning only   DS_BLS_739.dat

Comment: @user1643763: With a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) and GNU sed: `sed -nE '/DS_BLS_[0-9]*\.dat/{s/.*(DS_BLS_[0-9]*\.dat).*/\1 &/p}' file | sort -V | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2-`